# Изменение размеров дочернего элемента с центрированием и сохранением пропорций

Tags: css

### Описание

То, что мне нужно очень похоже на `vmin` и `vmax`, но не одно и тоже.
К примеру, `vmin` возвращает процент от наименьшего из размеров **экрана** (точнее viewport, не смог точно переводить).
Мне нужно что-то, что возвращает процент от наименьшего из размеров **родителя**.

### Вопрос

Есть ли такое, способ без костылей?
Ну... конечный вариант, есть способ с костылями?

---

### Дополнительно

##### Минимальный пример

```css
div#parent {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
}

div#child {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);">
  <div id="child" style="background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Давайте лучше так, расскажите нам зачем вам это нужно (то-есть саму задачу/проблему) и возможно найдётся другое решение.

Comment: @ΝNL993 есть у меня блок (далее родитель) - часто меняющий размеры. Внутри него другой блок - с пропорциями 1 : 1. Мне надо независимо от размера родителя увеличить дочерний блок насколько это возможно сохраняя пропорции.

Comment: @ΝNL993 я нашел куча методов - как реализовать такое с помощью JS и даже CSS, но они все в костылях. И каждый из них в каком-то браузере выдает проблему.

Comment: @ΝNL993 вопрос не к теме. Что вы редактировали в моем вопросе и зачем?

Comment: Во-первых, неплохо бы минимальный пример разметки и стилей. Во-вторых, за счёт чего меняются размеры родителя - ресайз, изменения DOM, скрипты? В-третьих, _"... независимо от размера родителя увеличить дочерний блок..."_, т.е. у дочернего блока `position: absolute` ?

Comment: @UModeL 1: Добавил. 2: От разных причин, может изменится за счет скриптов, может от resize. Для удобности будем считать что resize. 3: Имел ввиду, что дочерний элемент должен "заполнять" родителя (это масштабирование по англ. называется fit-parent)

Comment: @eccs0103 `Что вы редактировали в моем вопросе и зачем?` -- изменил способ того, как вы делаете line break. Вы используете `\\n`, а по идее надо `ㅤ  ` (то-есть, двойной пробел)

Comment: @ΝNL993 `Вы используете \\n, а по идее надо ㅤ   (то-есть, двойной пробел)` - а где написано, что так **надо**? Такое правило есть где-то, что `\n` неправильный?

Comment: @eccs0103 да и вправду, я перепроверил и по CommonMark оба способа верны. (И не `\n`, а `\\n`. Я под этим подразумевал \ + Enter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, Вам нужно добиться поведения схожего с `object-fit: contain`, только не для картинки, а для блока.

Предложу вариант с абсолютным позиционированием и автоотступами:

```css
div#parent {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  /* For example only --> */ overflow: hidden; resize: both;
}

div#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  /* For example only --> */ box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);">
  <div id="child" style="background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);"> </div>
</div>
```

*Чтобы посмотреть эффект в действии, измените размер родительского блока, ухватив его за правый нижний угол.*

Comment: Полезная ссылка: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Comment: Спасибо. Это то, что нужно. Ещё подскажите - на что изменить заголовок вопроса, чтобы ваш ответ можно было легко обнаружить с помощью него? Мне кажется мой вариант, слегка неправильный.

Comment: @eccs0103, "Изменение размеров дочернего элемента с центрированием и сохранением пропорций"

Answer (score 0):

вот мой кусок кривого кода. Юзается для масштаба по минимальной стороне ,а от переменой уже стили пляшут как хотят .Там и % можно получить который тебе нужно.
Цифры это вроде конкретно под мой проект можешь удалить их или оставить я уже не помню почему именно такие они за масштаб значения отвечают вроде. меняй window на кого хочешь и будет счастье.

```
    var world_size = ()=>{
                          var  SIZE_PX
                           if(window.innerHeight*1.243 > window.innerWidth) SIZE_PX = ~~parseInt(window.innerWidth*0.805*0.97)/8
                            else                                            SIZE_PX = ~~parseInt(window.innerHeight*0.97)/8

                             document.body.style.setProperty('--world_size',  SIZE_PX+'px')    
    }
                         window.onload = world_size
                         window.addEventListener('resize',  world_size, true);
```

юзал как то так

```
chat_box {
    height: calc(var(--world_size)/2.2); 
     width: calc(var(--world_size)/2.2);
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что не надо использовать JS. Я сам с помощью JS могу реализовать это несколько разными способами.